# How would I make a C-function that I can call from Lua?

Tags: c, function, lua, call, libraries

I would like to know how to make a C-function and be able to tell Lua about it, then call it from Lua. I have all the Lua Libraries installed on my Mac OSX 10.4 computer.

Answer (score 7):

There's an excellent example of Lua-C integration [here](https://github.com/adamwiggins/lua-pong) and [here](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/1/27/lua_the_embeddable_game_scripting_language/).

If you just need to export a function into the global namespace, then:

1. Declare the function (let's call it `f`) with signature `lua_CFunction`.
2. Call `lua_register(L, "myfunc", f)`, with L being the Lua state, and function = `f`.
3. Run the lua code. Then `f` will be available in the global namespace as `myfunc`.

---

If you're going to use the stock interpreter then you might want to make a library. [This guy](http://members.chello.nl/~w.couwenberg/) wrote an article for [Lua Programming Gems](http://www.lua.org/gems/) that explains how to do it. The sources are available online.

Comment: Where in the lua-5.x.x file should I put this? should it be a .c file?

Comment: Wait, are you using the stock interpreter code or embedding lua in your own app?

Answer (score 3):

You can register functions using [luaL_register](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_register)

Look at some examples and explanation in [PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.html)

Answer (score 2):

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583786/looking-for-good-server-side-language-that-will-allow-players-to-upload-code-that/1593980#1593980) includes a nice, short example about making a very simple game using C and Lua together.  In my biased opinion, it's a great starting point.